# Reversão de Commit

Tags: git

galera tenho uma duvida, eu gostaria de retornar para um determinado commit e atribuir esse commit para uma determinada branch sem perder historico, por exemplo.

eu tenho uma branch de desenvolvimento, onde ela é lida por uma URL, quando estou desenvolvendo e quero mostrar ao meu cliente o que eu fiz em desenvolvimento, eu commito e boa, mas pode acontecer do que eu fiz nao ir pra producao naquele exato momento, então eu teria que retornar para o commite inicial colocar esse commite atribuido ao branch de desenvolvimento e ainda obter o histórico.

ha como fazer isso?

Comment: Cherry-pick? Acho que é o que deseja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, creio que você queira isto na sua branch de desenvolvimento:

```
--> C0 ---> C1 --> C1'
```

1. C0 é o commit antes do seu
2. C1 é quando commitou a alteração e mostrou para o cliente
3. C1' é quando reverteu a alteração feita, mas manteve o histórico do que ocorreu: fez o commit do C1 em develop.

Assim, é melhor usar o `git revert` passando o *hash* do commit C1:

```
git revert 25d025e3317f59882d03b7938ee500e86d858c33
```

Para encontrar o hash do commit, utilize o seguinte comando:

```
git log
```

Será o primeiro registro (de baixo para cima), parecido com isto: `25d025e3317f59882d03b7938ee500e86d858c33`

Se quiser voltar com a alteração após o revert, use o mesmo número de commit para aplicá-lo novamente na sua branch:

```
git cherry-pick 25d025e3317f59882d03b7938ee500e86d858c33
```

Comment: Então eu testei isso, ele deu certo em partes, o commit que eu quero nao ficou atribuido ao master.

Acho que deve usar alguma coisa parecida com o "reset"

Comment: Então é melhor seguir a resposta do egomesbrandao: coloque sua alteração em uma branch e apresente sua branch para o cliente, sem "contaminar" a master em nenhum momento.

Comment: O problema que eu ja teria "contaminado" a master entendeu? Tipo aqui onde trabalho o master é o que vai pro site, então eu fui fazendo as coisas, mas nao deu certo, então temos que retornar os commits para a master sem perder o historico entendeu?

Comment: Bruno, entendi. Mas recomendo que vocês tentem mudar este fluxo. Como eu dizia em uma outra equipe, a branch `master` deve ser "sagrada": tudo que entra lá é para ficar, é nosso código de produção. Você deveria mostrar para o cliente o código pronto em uma branch separada e só usar a master quando tiverem batido o martelo da alteração. Recomendo adicionar o que acabou de me dizer na sua questão, são informações importantes do seu fluxo que nos ajudará a responder melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Uma das estratégias de branch é Feature branch, nela você desenvolve cada feature em uma branch específica e depois faz um merge delas numa branch integradora. A branch de integração é o que você vai enviar para a release, e portanto você só faz a integração do código quando tiver certeza de que irá entrar na release.

Além de estratégias de branch, ter um planejamento de release é importante, pois, quando você está para fazer a entrega, já deveria ter passado por testes, deploy em um ambiente de homologação, e portanto o seu código já estará integrado na branch integradora, que é a origem do build de continuous integration.

Uma outra forma de você separar as features na entrega é fazer com feature flag, assim, se o cliente não aprovar neste momento, a funcionalidade é apenas desligada em um painel de administração, porém essa técnica é mais complexa e é utilizada em ambientes de grandes empresas ou em softwares muito complexos.

Comment: Para quem quiser se aprofundar em alguns workflows comuns: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows